# estimation of an error of definite integral $<10^{-3}$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Using $$\int_{0}^{1}{x^{x}}dx = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)^{n-1}}}{{n^{n}}}}.$$
>
> Estimate the Integral with an error of magnitude $<10^{-3}$

What i try

- Put $n=1$.Then sum is  $\displaystyle 1$
- Put $n=2$. Then sum is $\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}.$
- Put $n=3$. Then sum is $\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3^3}=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{27}\approx 0.78$
- Put $n=4$. Then sum is $\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3^3}-\frac{1}{256}=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{27}\approx 0.77$

How do i solve it Help me please, Thanks

Comment: With your rep this high, I wonder what's the real obstacle. $5^{-5}<10^{-3}$.

Comment: Thanks metamorphy  actually after proving integral is equal sum actually i did not realise it.